# Which frame work I have to use for video format conversion

Tags: video

I have a requirement to convert the format of video to another format such as .mov file to .wmv format,
.mov to mp4/mp3/mpeg-1 etc,
which frame work I have to use in cocoa for video format conversion.

can I use QuickTime Framework for this purpose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Akbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with pure Cocoa then you will need QTKit framework. However, unless things have changed with Lion, a lot of functionality is missing from QuickTime framework.

If you go with QuickTime then you probably need to use the CoreVideo framework as well.

Alternatively, you could consider the LGPL [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) library.